# La propiedad de Bean 'documento_Id' no es legible o tiene un método getter no válido

Tags: java, spring

Estoy aprendiendo Spring Boot y tengo un problema cuando intento mostrar formulario para ingresar datos a la base de datos, se genera el error "La propiedad de Bean 'documento_Id' no es legible o tiene un método getter no válido: ¿El tipo de retorno del getter coincide con el tipo de parámetro del setter?"
    Ojala puedan ayudarme.
    Gracias!!!!

```
Formulario
<form action="#" th:action="@{/comercial/addcomercial}" th:object="${comercial}" method="post">
        <div class="con">
            <header class="head-form">
                <h2>Order</h2>
                <p>Enter Trading information</p>
                <br>
            </header>
            <br>
            <div class="field-set">
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{documento_Id}" placeholder="Document ID" required /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{primer_nombre}" placeholder="Firts Name" required /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{segundo_nombre}" placeholder="Second Name" required /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{primer_apellido}" placeholder="Last Name" required /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{segundo_apellido}" placeholder="Second Last Name" /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{numero_contacto}" placeholder="Phone Number" required /><br>
                <input class="form-input" id="txt-input" type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Mail Addres" required /><br>

                <button class="send">Enviar</button>
                <button class="btn submits cancel">Cancelar
            </div>


Clase:
Getters and Setters
public String getDocumento_id() {
        return documento_id;
    }

    public void setDocumento_id(String documento_id) {
        this.documento_id = documento_id;
    }

parte del Controller
@GetMapping("/listcomercial")
    public ModelAndView listAllComercial() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(COMERCIAL_VIEW);
        mav.addObject("comercial", new Comercial());
        mav.addObject("comercial", comercialService.listAllComercial());
        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("/addcomercial")
    public String addComercial(@ModelAttribute("comercial") Comercial comercial) {
        comercialService.addComercial(comercial);
        return "redirect:/comercial/listComercial";
    }

Error:
```

Invalid property 'documento_Id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'documento_Id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Tienes tus notaciones de hibernate en el id?, es decir los bean, [mira](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero el link no me funciona

Comment: te refieres a:
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="idcomercial")
 private int idcomercial;

 @Column(name="documento_id")
 private String documento_id;

Comment: Si,solo que en los ids, se usa el tipo de dato ```Long``` si tu base crecerá mucho o ```int``` si tendrás pocos registros

Comment: Es una empresa pequeña, donde el tope de usuarios no pasa los 20 usuarios. Pero, como puedo solucionar éste error?